# Does Anri know that Mikado is the leader of Dollars or part of the Dollars?

Tags: durarara

Does Anri know that Mikado is the leader of Dollars or that he is part of the Dollars?

Comment: Anri knows that Mikado is in the Dollars and has known this since fairly early on (not sure when exactly; certainly at least by the end of season 1), but I'm not sure whether or not she's aware that Mikado is the founder of the Dollars.

Comment: Why does it matter anyways? I suspect if she did know, not much would have changed. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score -3):

She doesn't know, and Mikado doesn't know that Anri is Aika.

Comment: @senshin's comment implies that she does know, could you give some reasons why you think she doesn't know?